# How to rename a Java module in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, module

I have generated the javafx-sample application from the javafx-archetype-simple archetype with maven:generate. Imported the maven project into Eclipse and it worked. After renaming the generated org.openjfx package and module to my.openjfx, Eclipse cannot start the App any more. There is a single line of error message in the console:

```
java.lang.module.FindException: Module org.openjfx not found
```

How to fix the problem? It works if started from maven command line like this:

```
mvn clean javafx:run
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround: First deleted the project from Eclipse and deleted the .classpath, .project and .settings files and directories, then imported the maven project and it worked.

The question is still valid, is there a simpler way to rename a module than deleting and re-importing the project?